# Телеграмм бот aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу создать бота, который удаляет все сообщения, оставленные в первые 30 секунд в комментариях

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
import time
max_time = 30
...
сделать пост
start_time = time.time() 
while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:
    сюда вставьте функцию удаления комментариев, если она существует, я таковой не нашёл =)
```

Comment: Если не знаете ответ, лучше не писать ответ.

Comment: Я написал ему, если он не знает как сделать, чтобы в *первые 30 секунд* удалялись комментарии

Comment: "*Если не знаете грамматики, лучше не писать грамматику*"

Comment: Ответ вам :))))

Comment: Это другое. Ответы != грамматика.

Comment: Я знаю, спасибо :З А ответ я всё-таки знаю

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.utils import executor
from datetime import datetime
import time

# Замените 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' на токен вашего бота
API_TOKEN = ''

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
async def delete_reply_to_channel_post(message: types.Message):
    # Получаем время отправки сообщения, на которое пользователь отвечает
    postDate_str = message.reply_to_message.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    postDate = datetime.strptime(postDate_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Получаем текущее время
    messageDate_str = message.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    messageDate = datetime.strptime(messageDate_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Вычисляем разницу во времени
    time_difference = (messageDate - postDate).total_seconds()
    
    # Проверяем, было ли сообщение отправлено более чем 30 секунд назад после сообщения в канале
    if time_difference > 30:
        return
    
    # Проверяем, является ли сообщение ответом на пост в канале
    if message.reply_to_message.forward_from_chat and message.reply_to_message.forward_from_chat.type == 'channel':
        # Удаляем сообщение, если его текст длиннее 30 символов
        if len(message.text) > 30:
            await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: ответы от чатгпт тут не приветствуются

Comment: разницы нет работает